# Spinner in RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-spinner

I am working on an app, In which I have a update data activity to modify the previous data. In this, I have created a recycler view. I want to fetch data from firebase database and set the spinner according to the value in the firebase. I am using a adapter for data in the spinner, so when I am trying to find the index of the data in the spinner using spn.getSelectedItemPosition() and passing the string on it, it shows string does not work while using adapter for spinner. How to use the spinner in recycler view please help.. Here is my code:

```
public class ArrangementAdminAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArrangementAdminAdapter.ArrangementAdminHolder> {

    ArrayList<Arrangements> list;
    public ArrangementAdminAdapter(ArrayList<Arrangements> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArrangementAdminHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.arrangement_admin_update,parent,false);
        return new ArrangementAdminHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ArrangementAdminHolder holder, int position) {

        Arrangements a = list.get(position);
        holder.date.setText(a.getDate());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ArrangementAdminHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        EditText date;
        Spinner spnTeacher, spnArrangedBy, spnClass, spnTime;

        public ArrangementAdminHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrangement_date);
            spnTeacher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spnTeacher);
            spnClass = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spnClass);
            spnArrangedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spnArrangedBy);
            spnTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spnTime);
            LoadTeacherSpinner();
            LoadClassSpinner();
            LoadTimeSpinner();

        }

        public void LoadTeacherSpinner(){
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(itemView.getContext(),
                    R.array.teachers_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spnTeacher.get
            spnTeacher.setAdapter(adapter);
            spnArrangedBy.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        public void LoadClassSpinner(){
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(itemView.getContext(),
                    R.array.class_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spnClass.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        public void LoadTimeSpinner(){
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(itemView.getContext(),
                    R.array.time_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spnTime.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want get index of spinners in RecyclerView , am i right?